# How can we animate the ipad view like a book

Tags: ipad, animation

I want to animate the view in ipad like a book, view should be turned like a page from right to left and vice versa. Can anyone provide me any tutorial or example for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check link

[UIPageViewController](http://www.ioslearner.com/implementing-uipageviewcontroller-programatically-without-storyboarding/)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html)
See e.g. this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application)

Answer (score 1):

```
 CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setDelegate:self];
        [animation setDuration:1.0f];
        animation.startProgress = 0.2;
        animation.endProgress   = 1;
        [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [animation setType:@"pageCurl"];

        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];

        [animation setFillMode: kCAFillModeBackwards];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```

for flipping the other way you make :

```
 [animation setType:@"pageUnCurl"];
```

Hope this helps, good luck :)

Comment: Giving error in this line: [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

Comment: I have tried this code and its working fine. what is the error shown?

Comment: anyway this line of code is not essential you can comment it out and run again your function, I tried it. Hope it works!